# Paperclip - permission denied (controller)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, permission-denied, folder-permissions

Well, i'm a new linux/rails student and some problems I just get so blind to solve. I've been digging stackoverflow and google to solve this one, but sincerly I cant. Only thing I know that is related with chmod and chown commands. "Anuncios" is my table as you can see.

error image:
[image]

I known the error reason is paperclip because I can create a entry without uploading a image.
App running in Ubuntu. RoR 4.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you specified a path option in has_attached_file? It seems like there is no write access on the uploaded file path. So you are getting error while saving the record with an image.

Comment: By default, uploaded file path is ':rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename' Probably, if this path not exists - permission denied occures

Comment: If the path doesn't exist then it is created by paperclip. I think the problem is with permissions or ownership. Paperclip created the system folder and tried to create a sub folder anuncios in it and that resulted in error as the permission was denied.

Comment: Hmm, thats is more reasonable. I've tried something about permissions and ownership and but doenst work. I'll post my permissions later. This is a better way to solve it than reinstalling ImageMagick as me and Vitalyp spoked, isnt it? Edit: alright, here is my permissions and ownership to dir bin, at /usr/: drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 65536 Fev 11 23:33 bin

Comment: And I wonder if the problem is related with permissions/ownership; in the same project there's another table where I upload images and it works fine (this one I get made by a coworker). If this first uploader works, any other that comes after should work fine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/Anuncios isn't your `table` (maybe, you mean desktop?). 
Your Desktop at ~/Desktop -or- /home/Anuncios/Desktop

/Anuncios looks like 'system dir', and it not exists

Comment: Hello, Vitalyp. Sorry, maybe I'm confusing some concepts. Anuncios is my table at db, as Anuncio is the model and anuncios_controller is my controller - Am I wrong? The only /anuncios that I found is view dir, at "myapp/app/view/anuncios", where is located new.html.erb and etc.

Comment: What is your 'has_attached_file :' arguments?

Comment: has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

same as documentation

Comment: ..and where you store uploaded files?
check the 'config.paperclip_defaults' option.

Comment: I guess is this /usr/bin/, as development.rb file points:
  #Paperclip
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"
  config.assets.debug = true

I dont saw this as a possible source of error because i'm coding on a existing project with another upload image method using paperclip.

Comment: You need change this location. Paperclip cannot access that folder.

Comment: Paperclip.options[:command_path] is a path to executable module, it is not that you need

Comment: Paperclip.options[:command_path] just tells paperclip where ImageMagick is installed.

Comment: So, should I change the dir where ImageMagick drops the images? I saw some problem solved that way or something nearly liked.

Comment: Yep. Look for 'config.paperclip_defaults' configuration options. Reread the gem manual.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thanks Vitalyp and Kirti Thorat.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

A coworker of mine help me and he said that in my controller I was using a rails 4 convetion [put filtrated params -> @anuncio = Anuncio.new(anuncio_params)] that used to be at model in rails 3; sometimes rails bug out due this change. Just swift anuncio_params by params[:anuncio].

**TL,DR:**

Sometimes rails bugs due some syntax version changes. Just substitute in my controller this:
    #@anuncio = Anuncio.new(anuncio_params)
for this:
    @anuncio = Anuncio.new(params[:anuncio]) and works!

Thanks Vitalyp and Kirti Thorat for the contribution. Ps: nothing relative to Image Magick.